# Cleaning up magento.stackexchange.com: Join #magestackday!

Tags: discussion, community, event

It's time to clean up our loved Magento Stackexchange site!

On 7. + 8. November we will do an online "hackathon" (more a magestackoverflow-athon, official on twitter: **#magestackday**) dedicated to answering, closing and cleaning up questions on magento.stackexchange.com. The goal is to raise the answered questions rate up by at least a few percent and work on those (currently) [2163 unanswered questions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)

Whoever is willing to help us, please sign up via the #magestackday website:

https://sites.google.com/site/magestackday/

If you're planning to host a local event to socialize and answer/work together, please tick the checkbox in the registration form and we will contact you with detailed information.

**Suggestions? Questions?**
Please contact [Sander Mangel](https://twitter.com/sandermangel) or [me](https://twitter.com/rescueAnn).

Looking forward to your participation!

Comment: I have some doubts about this megaevent. I have posted a question for this here http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/394/what-are-the-special-plans-on-magestackday . Have a look and please give us an answer :-)

Comment: Why are you deleting all questions ? In future some people will surely answer these questions ! :( please dont delete Questions .

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird some questions are of very low quality and are not really adding anything to the forum. Those will be deleted

Comment: can you at least let us edit questions or something? Those of us looking for assistance probably need help, regardless of how tidy you wish your site to look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update:

Thanks everyone for your participation!

Please follow this link for the recap:
[MageStackDay recap](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/409/magestackday-recap)

---

I will sum up all arising questions here. Updates to come.

**Is there any personal interactions possible (via skype or whatever)?**

We will have some online sessions on Skype/Google Hangout/Slack/whatever. More information to come.

**What about people who cannot physically available in particular location (I am from india. I know I would be alone when participate in this event. :-( But having an online support is better right ?)**

It's not about going somewhere physically. You can also join from home, your office, wherever. That's what an online-event is all about :-) You can work remote, join the online sessions, join a local event or not (or host one yourself) to gather with people around you.

**Do questions divide into different category so that people who are more interested to a particular category can answer that section?**

We don't want to overmanage the event. Use your favourite tags on magento stackexchange. If not everyone starts answering on page "1" we should be able to work on several questions at once. And I guess it will naturally happen that people prefer different questions to answer.

**Is there any special plans to make this event a great success?**

The key to success is the participation of YOU and the magento stackexchange community!

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @programmer_rkt : Why are you deleting all questions ? In future some people will surely answer these questions ! :( please dont delete Questions .

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird : I didnt get you ? Where did I delete a question ??!!!!

Comment: @programmer_rkt : read title : `Cleaning up magento.stackexchange.com: ` You are also going to delete ,close questions correct?   :(

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird : oh no.. it is not at all like that. we are organizing a program called "magestackday" in which community members gather together and answer all unanswered questions in order to increase the answer rate in this community. Event is going to held on nov 7,8 . "clean" is used in a good way here, not like you guessed. Please go through the content. You are most welcome to the program :-)

Comment: @programmer_rkt : is it for free ?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird : of course yes. it is an online event. you need to dedicate your two days or at least one day or the time that you have for this event on Nov 7 & 8. Let us make this event a great success by work together.

Answer (score 4):

During the tea time, I think about this event. For the great success of this event I have some suggestions to put forward. I don't know how much of this possible, but it may make much difference if we care about this aspects.

1. In order to make this event a great success, we need to spread this news ASAP. We all need to take this as our own responsibility. I am so much excited when I hear about this news. It was my dream to be a part of one of magento hackathon/magento meet. This is somewhat a dream come true. I am sure there are lot of developers who are just like me to do anything for this community. So we need to catch them, atleast they should know about this event before the D-DAY.
2. As like gathering all community active members, it is very much important that, we need to inform this event to new comers or people who came here rarely. So that they will came to know about this event and may promote this program. For this, one of my suggestion is that, we need to "proclaim" about this event in magento community page(May be in right section, just like an ad). This way all people came to know about this event.
3. I am  a regurlar user of this community. I will go through almost 60% of questions that are raised in a day. From that experience, I can say that most of the questions posted here are "less-descriptive" now a days. Means we cannot understand what the questioner actually need. It may be due to they are not providing necessary codes, due to lack of awareness etc. However I am sure that during the event, we all will come to a conclusion that about 50% (at least) of unanswered questions cannot be answered due to its poor content !!!!! So in order to avoid this, my suggestion is that we need to do a pre-review section of unanswered questions. That is we need to go through old-unanswered-questions and ping the questioner about this event and request them to edit their own question in better way so that we can answer them.

I know there may be some practical difficulties to do this. But for the success of this maga event, I think these filtering is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add to this, every member on here can help generate awareness to the cause, to both people to participate and for users of the site to appreciate that answers need to be marked as accepted.

To do my bit, I've changed my profile to support the cause, I think others in turn should follow suit,

1. Change your username to `MageStackDay Needs You ...`
2. Change/prefix your profile description to:

   > #Stack Exchange Needs You!
   >
   > If you've found magento.stackexchange.com to be helpful, then you need to help the site back. It is at risk from being decommissioned due to the question:answer ratio and answer rate.
   >
   > Whether you are a genius, or someone that needs help, you can still contribute.
   >
   > - Geniuses can help by marking answering the unanswered questions
   >   - Others can help simply by marking good answers as accepted, or upvoting other     answers they see value in
   >
   > For more information see, [https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393/cleaning-up-magento-stackexchange-com-join-magestackday]([Cleaning up magento.stackexchange.com: Join #magestackday!](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393/cleaning-up-magento-stackexchange-com-join-magestackday))
   >
   > ---
3. Add a little badge to your site avatar to promote the cause (download here https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mye6.png). I've even taken the liberty of making the avatars for the top contributors here, so they can focus on writing top quality answers :) (Sorry if I didn't make your avatar! Post a comment here, or re-tweet https://twitter.com/sonassi/status/529953245444444160 and I'll do it)

[image: Anna]
[image: Marius]
[image: Philwinkle]
[image: Fabian]
[image: Sander]
[image: David]
[image: Alan]
[image: Benmarks]
[image: Tim]
[image: Vinai]
[image: Amit]
[image: DavidA]
[image: Barry]
[image: BlankImg]

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!

Comment: Thank *you* for starting the campaign.

Comment: Awesome! thanks