# MageStackDay recap

Tags: discussion, magestackday

Over 50 developers, from 15 nationalities answering 189 questions, earning 207 badges getting the acceptance rate up from 68.62% to 70.48%. Even after these two days the answer rate continued to climb.
When we started brainstorming about MageStackDay a few weeks ago we never imagined it would be such a success or how much support we would get from the community. Maybe the twitter stats say it best: 208 tweets with the #magestackday hashtag reaching over 199.000 people having 630 retweets in just 1 or 2 weeks.

Please let us know, how you liked the MageStackDay by filling out the feedback form:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1K1VcoNKaJ90kwNfOhmNrWvE9uhKAwyQ1gh1p6ZdromU/viewform?usp=send_form#start=invite

We hope to do this again very soon and in the mean time we will keep the slack group open and hope everybody will keep answering questions (and closing where needed) to keep Magento StackExchange on track!

On a side note, here are the #MagePetDay results

- 4 cats
- 3 dogs
- 1 rat
- 1 pinguin (unconfirmed)

We’re awesome, you’re awesome, magentoSE is becoming (again) more awesome, thanks for your participation & time!

Sander and Anna